# how to write a complete server client communication using java nio

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I am new to java NIO. I have to write a simple server client communication program using Java NIO.

Is there any sample programs or any link where can I go for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might give a look at [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/). If you only want to learn java NIO it might me a little to hard to grasp.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your co-operation Finally I have created socket client program.

Answer (score 25):

**Apache Mina**
http://mina.apache.org
Apache MINA is a network application framework which helps users develop high
performance and high scalability network applications easily.

**xSocket**
http://xsocket.org/
xSocket is an easy to use NIO-based library to build high performance, highly
scalable network applications.

**JBoss Netty**
http://netty.io/
The Netty project is an effort to provide an asynchronous event-driven network 
application framework and tools for rapid development of maintainable high performance and high scalability protocol 
servers and clients.

**Sun MicroSystem's Grizzly**
https://grizzly.java.net/
The Grizzly framework has been designed to help developers to take advantage of the Java NIO API.
Grizzly goals is to help developers to build scalable and robust servers using NIO.

**NIO Framework**
http://nioframework.sourceforge.net
The NIO Framework is a library on top of NIO that hides most of the complexity of 
plain NIO. With the NIO Framework you can implement high-performance Java network 
applications without having to deal with all the nasty details of NIO.

**QuickServer**
http://www.quickserver.org
QuickServer is an open source Java library/framework for quick creation of 
robust multi-client TCP server applications. QuickServer provides an abstraction over 
the ServerSocket, Socket and other network and input output classes and it eases the 
creation of powerful network servers.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in your JDK under the directory called *sample*

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you should take a look on [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) if your applcation uses HTTP, of course. There are several examples provided within downloadable library archive. Note that httpcore, httpcore-nio and httpclient are part of the project.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the online tutorials available. [Building Highly Scalable Servers with Java NIO](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/09/01/nio.html) looks particularly relevant.

IBM has a [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/edu/j-dw-java-nio-i.html) (registration required) whilst Sun has some simple [examples](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/example/index.html) of the different facilities of NIO (not just client/server APIs)